# Audio no longer working after AMD Catalyst install, Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, xubuntu, intel, catalyst

On a fresh Xubuntu install today I installed `fglrx-updates`, `fglrx-amdcccle-updates` and `fglrx-updates-dev` and, after restarting, everything worked fine apart from audio. The volume indicator is greyed out and there are no sound options to be found anywhere. I installed pavucontrol and xfce4-mixer but neither of them will open, and every time I try to play a song, the music player (I've tried VLC and gmusicbrowser) either freezes or sits at 0:00. Firefox hangs and eventually needs to be forced closed if I try to watch a video on Youtube or elsewhere.

`lspci | grep Audio` returns the following:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05) 
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device aab0
```

EDIT: I'm using a Radeon HD 7750 card. I'm not using the HDMI audio from it, but two speakers that are plugged into the port for the onboard audio.

Comment: uninstall catalyst, i have experience with it, it makes ubuntu unstable.. use ubuntu drivers instead

Comment: @user1262738 What drivers are those? The default drivers I started with restricted me to 4:3 on my 16:9 screen.

Answer (score 2):

[George A.](https://askubuntu.com/users/149271/george-a) solved the problem in his question:

> The problem must lie with Pulseaudio, as I followed the instructions [here](http://howto.blbosti.com/2010/04/ubuntu-make-alsa-default-instead-of-pulseaudio/) to uninstall it and, after rebooting, everything worked perfectly!